# Schedule a task to run before a service starts

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-services

I would like to ensure that a task runs before a particular service is started. (The service is "automatic"). Is there any way to do this?

I could schedule a task to run on startup, and just pray. But will it begin before the service is started? It's a very short task, is it likely to complete before the service is started?

I guess I could change the service to "manual", and have my startup task start it. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Set your service's "Startup type" to [Automatic (Delayed Start)](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DelayedStart) to ensure that your scheduled task completes before the service is run.

Comment: @CoreTech: Choosing Delayed Start isn't a guarantee that the task will be completed before the service is started.

Comment: @Rob: Your solution (have your task start the service once it's done) is the best way to guarantee that there will be no conflict or overlap.